# How to scroll texts and append to last using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to make some text scroll to left of a screen and then when "text 1" is out of view, it should append to the back of the last text and so on.
So far I've managed to make it scroll but not append, I don't have an idea on how to do so.
I would also like all texts to be shown on the screen before it starts scrolling.

```
.scroll
{
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Markup

```
<div class="scroll" id="scroller">
<span>Text 1 </span><span>Text 2 </span><span>Text 3 </span><span>Text 4 </span><span>Text 5 </span><!--ETC... -->
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var scroller = $('#scroller'); // scroller $(Element)
var scrollerWidth = scroller.width(); // get its width
var scrollerXPos = window.innerWidth; // init position from window width
var speed = 1.5;
scroller.css('left', scrollerXPos); // set initial position

function moveLeft() {
    if(scrollerXPos <= 0 - scrollerWidth) scrollerXPos = window.innerWidth;
    scrollerXPos -= speed;
  scroller.css('left', scrollerXPos);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
}
    window.requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
});
```

Comment: so when Text 1 is off the screen, you want it appended back to the beginning? Or as you said, _append to the back of the last text_ .. I guess meaning it gets moved to after Text5? Pls clarify

Comment: Yes, I want it to get moved after Text5 and then when Text2 is out of the screen, it should move after the Text1 that was moved earlier.